# How to type in a field with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I'm running this command in the terminal:

```
chromium --remote-debugging-port=8081 https://google.com
```

This will open the browser on the Google page with remote debugging enabled on port 8081, accessing localhost:8081 and pressing F12 we will see that there are 2 devtools on the page, it should look like this:

This will open the browser on the Google page with remote debugging enabled on port 8081, accessing localhost:8081 and pressing F12 we will see that there are 2 devtools on the page

**Guys, what I need to do is run a javascript code in the first devtool (the one with the largest width), and I need this code to be able to type in the second devtool and give an enter, for example, I want to use the first devtool to put an alert in the first devtool in the type field and then enter.**

**How can I fill the input of the second devtool and enter with a javascript code in the first devtool?**

I would like to add an image to make it clearer but I don't have 10 reputation if you find the question helpful of a positive vote please I want to improve it

Comment: Maybe you can better explain why you want to do this ?

Comment: @davidonet An automation with Selenium, I didn't post the code because I've got everything ready, but that's just missing, I can use driver.execute_script, but it'll do the same, if I can't type in the second devtool with a javascript code and run I'll have to use send_keys , normally this is slow, so I want to do this, it's the only thing left

Comment: Maybe try https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/